# Passing a variable between methods inside the same activity

Tags: variables, android-sqlite

Within the MainActivity I've two main methods. One is a cursor and the other is a spinner. Within the cursor method, I retrieve some data from the SQlite database to be used as variables.

in MainActivity

```
            //reinserted EGG outside
            String EGG;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


                  .....
           private void gettree() {
        Cursor cursor = db.getBall();
        cur(cursor);                
            }}

        public  void cur(Cursor ur) {
             int orange = 0;
                    if (ur.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
              int apple = ur.getInt(0);
              orange = 0 + apple;
                       } while(ur.moveToNext());
        }
        ur.close();
             //the EGG variable
        int EGG = orange;
                 }}


            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView,
             View view, int i, long l) {

              //eclipse does not recognize EGG here
        Toast.makeText(this, EGG, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       
        Spinner clink = (Spinner)adapterView;

if(clink.getId() == R.id.dpz)
    {   TextView mysdp =(TextView) view;
        ....                
    }}
```

in DatabaseAdapter

```
             public Cursor getBall() {

        String[] A = new String[] {"first"};


        String condition = "_id = '1'";
        Cursor e =  db.query(true, "maintable", A, 
                        condition, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (returnee != null) {         
            e.moveToFirst();
        }
        return returnee;
    }
```

What I hope to do is use the EGG variable to the onItemSelected method for the spinner using the fastest and most efficient way. I'm new to android and I'm not sure exactly how to do this. I tried declaring the EGG variable but it does not update (in fact eclipse says its not being used).

Do I have to reaccess the getBall to get the variable from inside the onItemSelected method and I'm not sure how to do that. I guess I am really hoping for a more simple way to access the EGG variable I've already found in the first method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want a variable to be accessible from various different methods, then declare it outside any of your methods (so it will be a member variable). And don't mark primitive variables final unless they are constants that will never change.

Comment: Your line `int EGG = orange;` is declaring a new variable with the same name as your other variable named `EGG`. When you declare a new variable, it is only usable within the braces it was declared in, and if it has the same name as a variable outside those braces, it "hides" the outer variable so the outer variable cannot be used. Hiding variables is permitted by the compiler but is likely to cause unintended bugs. In your case you do `int EGG = orange;` right before a closing brace, so that line is storing the value of `orange` in a new int variable, before immediately throwing it away.

Comment: Thanks. I've changed the final declaration and tried accessing the EGG from inside the onitemSelected, but its not recognized

Comment: See my first comment.

Comment: I get what you mean now. Thanks. I will try to put the whole get tree thing outside and see if it works. Appreciate you pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Tenfour04, I've declared the variable outside of the class and its viewable across the activity.